# Category.php template for custom posts

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, php

I'm trying to use my category.php file to display all posts of a certain custom post type (say "Company") with a given category. However, when I try to use it by navigating to domain.com/category/company/category1, which is the link automatically generated by wp_list_categories(), no posts appear.

The code I'm using is:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'type-company', get_post_format() ); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out! For anyone having the same problem, I solved it by adding

```
$cat_id = get_query_var('cat'); 
query_posts("post_type=company&cat=$cat_id");
```

right in front of the loop. Anyone having the same problem would probably also benefit from looking at [this](http://www.slideshare.net/williamsba/custom-post-types-and-taxonomies-in-wordpress), too.

Comment: But this would not fetch child category posts? How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is to use [pre_get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) for that.

You can either add to show at the search.php and other pages from template hierarchy, like so:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', function($query) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {

        if ( is_archive() || is_category() ) {
            $query->set( 'post_type', 'company' );
        }

        if ( $query->is_search() ) {
            $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'company' ) );
        }
    }
});
```

To understand more about `pre_get_posts()` you should [watch this talk of Andrew Nacin](http://wordpress.tv/2012/06/15/andrew-nacin-wp_query/) (one of the leader developers of WP)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the core `category` taxonomy, by applying it to your Custom Post Type, or have you defined a *custom* taxonomy?

If you're using a *custom* taxonomy, you need to use the template file `taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php`, or `taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php`.

But really, using `category.php` or `taxonomy.php` really may not be what you want to do. Have you tried using `archive-{post-type}.php`, for displaying the archive index list of posts from your Custom Post Type?

You also have an issue with this:

```
<?php get_template_part( 'type-company', get_post_format() ); ?>
```

The Post Format taxonomy only applies to the *Post* post-type; not to any, arbitrary post-type. Again: did you custom-apply the Post Format taxonomy to your Custom Post Type?

**EDIT**

Note: you may need to modify the Loop query in `category.php` and/or `tag.php`, in order to display your CPTs.

Comment: I'm using the core `category` taxonomy for my Custom Post Type; the blog itself does not use categories. I could create an `archive-{post-type}.php` document, but I need to only display the posts in a given category, so `category.php` seems like a natural choice.

Comment: I've fixed the issue with `get_post_format()`: I'm now using `get_template_part( 'content-company' );` and I've also tried `type-company` and `single-company`—none work.

Comment: Do you have template-part files named `content-company.php`, `type-company.php`, or `single-company.php`?

Comment: Yes, I do. Do I need to store them somewhere in particular? They're in the root of my theme folder.

Comment: Alternatively, do I need to use a special variant of the loop, or add a query before it?

Comment: What is the content of those template-part files? Given its use location, it might make more sense to call the appropriate template-part file `loop-company.php`, and then call `get_template_part( 'loop', 'company' )`. But, `get_template_part()` is just a fancy wrapper for `locate_template()`, which is an equal-opportunity `include()` function.

Comment: The content of these files is based on [Toolbox](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/toolbox), with few modifications.

Comment: I also tried renaming the files, but that didn't work.

Comment: For what it's worth, the tag archives in the blog section of the site weren't bringing up Company posts when they had tags, rather than categories, attached to them...